# Delivering unzipped file through servlet without unzipping on server first

Tags: java, http, servlets, compression, zip

On the network where I have my web server there is a machine that has many zipped pdf files (zipped using java.util.zip) and I can access these files through HTTP. When a user wants to download a pdf file, I know how to unzip the file locally on the server first and then deliver the unzipped pdf to the user through a servlet. Is it possible to deliver the unzipped file to the user without unzipping it locally first?

Regards

Comment: Do you mean, instruct the browser to unzip the file automatically at arrival?

Comment: Either this, or if the browser can't do it, then somehow decompress it so that the end-user can receive it decompressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, if the client has said in his request that he accepts gzip-compressed data, you could send the PDF file in compressed form, and the client will decompress it. There is a gotcha, though: While the compression algorithm of zip files and the HTTP `Content-Encoding: gzip` is the same, the Zip file format has some more things around it (since it can contain multiple files, and a directory structure), so it would be necessary to strip these things off before. I'm not sure this would be much easier than decompressing in your servlet and then let your Servlet-engine take care of compressing again, but try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the response to a request, encoded in a compressed format. If the client does the request with the header

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

you can for instance serve him the content compressed using gzip (as long as you declare this through a header:)

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Source: [Wikipedia: HTTP Compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression)

Comment: So, if the client accepts gzip, can I just serve the file that has been zipped with java.util.zip? Does gzip and java.util.zip use the same compression? Also, I want the user to receive the uncompressed file with the extension .pdf . Does that mean that I have to change the file name from extension .zip to .pdf or does the client do that automatically?

Comment: @Alex: gzip, Info Zip, PKZip and java.util.zip use the same compression algorithm, but gzip and zip are different file formats (as the last one can contain multiple files and even directory structures). java.util.zip.* supports both with different classes.

Comment: A simple way would be to save the files on the server as ".pdf.gz", then you can simply stream them. I would offer both the links to the full ".pdf.gz" (and then stream them without indicating Content-Encoding) and ".pdf" (then indicating `Content-Encoding: gzip`). Of course, you also should offer the appropriate `Content-Type`, so the browser can do some intelligent proposal in the safe-as box.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it possible to deliver the unzipped file to the user without unzipping it locally first?*

That depends a little bit on what exactly you mean with "locally", the general answer is "no". To deliver unzipped content, you have to unzip the zip first.

If you *actually* mean that the zip file is located at some non-local machine and that you currently need to save and zip it locally first before streaming unzipped content, then the answer would be "yes", it is possible to unzip and stream it without saving the file locally. Just pass/decorate the streams without using `FileInputStream`/`FileOutputStream`.